# OnlineGDB c++ not compiling strcpy_s

Tags: c++11, strcpy

I'm going to compile a very simple code on [onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)

The code is as below.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[10] = {0};
    
    strcpy_s(s, 10, "1234567890");
    
    printf("%s", s);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I chose option ***Language*** as `C++`, `C++14` and `C++17`, but all those are not compiling `strcpy_s`.

It says:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:16:33: error: ‘strcpy_s’ was not declared in this scope
     strcpy_s(s, 10, "1234567890");
                                 ^
```

I googled minutes, but there was no answer.

Doesn't gdb online support c compiler above c++11 ? Help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy:

> As with all bounds-checked functions, `strcpy_s` is only guaranteed to be available if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined by the implementation and if the user defines `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to the integer constant 1 before including `string.h`.

You haven't checked whether `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined (it's not defined by whatever compiler onlinegdb.com is using), and you haven't indicated that you *want* `strcpy_s` at all.

Comment: thx. i've tested and realized that onlinegdb doesn't support it. I'll change online c++ site for next time.

Comment: Ahh, I've found that linux compilers such as `gcc` or `g++`  don't support `strcpy_s()`. My target is to compile for windows c++, so i have to find online windows compilers.